# Can I increase the performance of this Python code?

Tags: python, c++, performance, optimization

I have written the following simple loop in Python. It uses floating point additions and multiplications  to sum the squares of the integers from 0 to 1.0e9 - 1. (This is a toy example, but I believe it is representative of the code I am currently writing).

```
a = 0.0
i = 0.0
while i < 1.0e9:
    a += i * i
    i += 1.0
print a
```

On my machine, using 32-bit CPython 2.7.8, this takes 400 seconds to run. The equivalent C++ code (below) runs in less than 2 seconds and the equivalent Go code in less than 3.

```
double a = 0.0;
for(double i = 0.0; i < 1.0e9; i += 1.0) {
    a += i * i;
}
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Since my code needs to be distributed to end users who may not have anything other than CPython installed, I am unable to use PyPy or NumPy to speed up the Python code.

Is there anything else I can do to increase the performance of the Python code, or for arithmetic heavy work will CPython generally be 100 times slower than C++ and Go?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using floats to represent values that will always be integers?

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine - I'm interested in floating-point performance. In my actual project code, the values are rarely integers.

Comment: @PaulBaker In that case, Paul, it would be fair to this Community to design rather a bit more representative example to be used for StackOverflow moderated research & discussion. This way you get right answers, but for a subject, that is not the one you will work with in your Project, resulting in a waste of all the efforts contributed to your question. You may want to define your task goal and priorities so as to better match your application / problem domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1) Use PyPy. On your program it goes about 30x faster:

```
$ time python sum.py
3.33333332833e+26

real    4m17.728s
user    4m17.465s
sys 0m0.107s
$ time pypy sum.py
3.33333332833e+26

real    0m7.973s
user    0m7.614s
sys 0m0.049s
```

2) Use a different algorithm. You can use algebra to get the same answer much faster. I know your real code is different than this toy example, but there still might be opportunities to reduce the work.

3) Use numpy, this is what it is for.  If you are dealing with arrays, numpy will be faster.

4) Use Cython.  I tried it on your Python code, and it ran in **.936 seconds** without any type declarations.

5) Use C or Go.  CPython will be slower, since it is interpreted, there is overhead for compute-bound processes.

Comment: Would you kindly add your benchmark outputs also for a precise ( decimal.Decimal ) computation? That would be quantitatively comparable then.

Comment: Plain python interpreted precise computation took **`849 [usec]`** on localhost, however principally not comparable with your figures on another machine.

Comment: I have not previously looked at Cython, but that result is quite impressive. Am I right in thinking you used Cython to convert my Python to C code, then compiled and benchmarked the C?

Comment: I've never used Cython before, I just followed these instructions to make a compiled extension that I imported into the Python program: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: n.b.: after many surprises, **one would rather not rely on demo-example performance results, as the real-world applications introduce more issues not present in demo-code** -- memory allocations, garbage collections, JIT-compilation and other overheads, to name just a few -- so real in-vivo performance comparison may be several orders of magnitude shifted towards another approach, that was in-vitro way "slower".

Comment: @user3666197 You seem very interested in adding many more factors to the original question.  I have no idea how much they apply or not.  I'm choosing to answer the simple question provided.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I appreciate both the efforts and insights you have introduced in a fair way into this topic, Ned. The remarks on real-world use of the demo-code just try to say that in-vitro performance results need not match the real-system ones. KISS principle is great, supposing the results do not get distorted. Validations are the very means to prove they are not. No one would like to find him/her-self to be onboard a plane, that nose-dives to crash, just due to accumulated  precision faults or unhandled case of numerical overflow.

Answer (score 2):

My machine is slower than yours so I'm still waiting for the result... but since we're talking sum of squares here, let's use some [maths](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm):

```
>>> n=1.0e9 - 1
>>> n**3/3 + n**2/2 + n/6
3.3333333283333336e+26
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get speed-ups with Cython, you need to specify types and use C data-types, not python `object` type;

`pilot.pyx` file which defines a function named `pilot`:

```
def pilot(long long n):
    cdef long long i = 0
    cdef long double a = 0

    while i < n:
        a += i * i
        i += 1

    return a
```

and result:

```
In [11]: from pilot import pilot

In [12]: int(pilot(1e9))
Out[12]: 333333332833334250415587328

In [13]: %timeit pilot(1e9)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop
```

note that, to avoid overflow, I have to use `long double` type for `a` even though it is integer; this will be at the cost of precision in the final result, though the *relative* error would be very small here (but, not the absolute error).

Comment: I got enormous speed-ups with Cython without adding any type declarations at all to the Python code.

Comment: @NedBatchelder see [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#faster-code-via-static-typing) and [this](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-typeinference)

Comment: yes, it will go even faster with type declarations.  But you get good speed-ups without adding any declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not much you can do in cPython, but you can use Cython to compile the critical parts to a native extension. Let's consider this snippet:

```
cdef double a = 0.0
cdef double i = 0.0
while i < 1.0e9:
    a += i * i
    i += 1.0
print a
```

Note the `cdef` part, which declares a static type for Python variables. Compiled with Cython will execute at almost-native speed, but will save you the hassle of hand-writing a C extension.

To be honest, writing an extension is not that difficult. So if you want to take advantage of the raw speed of C/C++, you might want to investigate [how to write one](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html). For instance, this will define a `modname.doit()` function that will perform the calculation:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject * doit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    double a = 0.0;
    double i;
    for(i = 0.0; i < 1.0e9; i += 1.0) {
        a += i * i;
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("d", a);
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"doit",  doit, METH_VARARGS, "Do stuff with numbers."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodname(void) {
    (void) Py_InitModule("beta", methods);
}
```

Save it as `modname.c` and compile it as a shared object. For example, on GNU/Linux:

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o modname.so modname.c
```

Both methods have the advantage of dramatically reducing computation times, but your application won't be cross-platform anymore. In fact, you will need to distribute a compiled native module for each platform you will be deploying to.

Answer (score 0):

### Any solution ought to be both fast and precise

There is **no faster solutio**n than the @uselpa proposed one.

**Precision** of the result is another issue.

Speed of **0.000 849 sec** of a demo-code is always to be taken into account **only with due care**, as noted in comments above.

```
# PRECISION ...................................................................
>>> import decimal
>>> n = decimal.Decimal( '1e9')
>>> n -= 1
>>> n
Decimal('999999999')

>>> n**3/3 + n**2/2 + n/6
Decimal('333333332833333333500000000.0')
# DIFF                   ^^^
#  int   33333333283333336..........
# DIFF                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# pilot  333333332833334250415587328


# SPEED ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
>>> import zmq                                          # import for a Real-Time clock
>>> aClk = zmq.Stopwatch()                              # having 0.000 001[sec]
>>> aClk.start();n**3/3 + n**2/2 + n/6;usec=aClk.stop() # TimeDOMAIN resolution
Decimal('333333332833333333500000000.0')                # Yes, a [usec] and
>>> usec                                                # can measure down
849L                                                    # to about 25[nsec]
                                                        # if setup correctly
```

**n.b.**: after many surprises, **one would rather not rely on demo-example performance results**, as the real-world applications introduce more issues not present in demo-code -- memory allocations, garbage collections, JIT-compilation and other overheads, to name just a few -- so real in-vivo performance comparison may be several orders of magnitude shifted towards another approach, that was in-vitro way "slower"